# Decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding

how to convert this output in javascript:

> a = 1.0000006
>
> b = 0.00005
>
> c = 2.54695621e-7

to this output:

> a = 1
>
> b = 5e-5
>
> c = 2.547e-7

Comment: Have you tried `.toFixed()` and/or `Math.round()`?

Comment: In the first case, use [*Math.round*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-math.round), for the others, use [*toExponential*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-number.prototype.toexponential) (the second example should be rounded to 2.547e-7).

Comment: @nnnnnn—how do you get *Math.round* or *toFixed* to do scientific notation?

Comment: How did you derive `5e-5` from `0.00005`?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't understand your comment, `5e-5` is just a different notation for `0.00005`, like `0xFF` is just a different notation for `255`

Comment: @Thomas How do you derive `5e-5` from `0.00005` by hand?

Comment: @RobG - Skill and daring. (Seriously though, I don't think I promised that those functions would handle all three cases...)

Comment: @Thomas `5e^-5 = 0.033689735` proof `5*Math.exp(-5)`,  `5e-5 = 8.591409142` proof `5*Math.E-5`. `e` is the mathematical irrational constant `2.718281828`. Not sure how a `javascript` function could convert `0.00005` to `5e-5`, if the function does produce `5e-5` from `0.0005`, the function is producing incorrect results; unless can be illuminated as to how the conversion is mathematically possible.

Comment: @guest271314 - Type "53e-5" into your browser's console and see what happens... In this context `e` isn't the constant 2.718etc, it is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

Comment: @nnnnnn _"Type "53-5" into your browser's console and see what happens..."_ Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry, typo, missed the "e".. I've edited my comment.

Comment: @nnnnnn Then OP is not actually performing math? Are you stating that OP is using `e` in a different context? Question does not mention hexidecimal. How does `3` come into the equation at `53e-5`? In math _`e`_ is is not ambiguous, _`e`_ is the base of natural logarithms, approximately `2.718281828`

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: @guest271314 - The "3" doesn't matter, "53e-5" was just an example. The point is that [as explained by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) some programming languages use "e" to mean "times 10 to the power of". This has nothing to do with the mathematical constant `e`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Then the Question concerns the `javascript` programming language notation, not actual math notation. That is an enlightening fact. Note, `e` is an irrational mathematical constant.

Comment: @guest271314 As others already mentioned, we're not dealing with the constant `e` here but with the so called [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) of a single number/value. `5e-5` is a shorthand for `5 * Math.pow(10, -5)`. I've seen this notation with both lowercase and uppercase `E` without any difference. For positive exponents the sign of the exponent is not required, so that `5e3`, `5E3`, `5e+3`, `5E+3` and `5000` are all equal. *This may be different for other programming languages*

Comment: @Thomas Yes, the Question concerns programming language notation, not formal math notation. A positive to be aware of when viewing `javascript` questions and answers where `e` is part of text. Would be clearer if disambiguation were present at both Question and Answer as to `e` not being the math notion _`e`_, but an artifact of the programming language itself. The mathematical irrational constant `e` is used in many applications, `e` meaning  _"times 10 to the power of"_ is used  at `javascript` or other programming languages alone, which should make an effort to not use `e` for that purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```js
var a = 1.0000006;
var b = 0.00005;
var c = 2.54695621e-7;
var a_Result = Math.round(a);
var b_Result = b.toExponential();
var c_Result = c.toExponential(3);
console.log(a_Result );
console.log(b_Result);
console.log(c_Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With this input:

```
var nums = [1.0000006, 0.00005, 2.54695621e-7];
```

you can use [`Number#toExponential`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) to get exponential notation with a certain precision:

```
function formatNumber(n) {
    return n.toExponential(3);
}

nums.map(formatNumber)
// ["1.000e+0", "5.000e-5", "2.547e-7"]
```

split it into useful parts:

```
function formatNumber(n) {
    return n
        .toExponential(3)
        .split(/[.e]/);
}

nums.map(formatNumber)
// [["1", "000", "+0"], ["5", "000", "-5"], ["2", "547", "-7"]]
```

and trim away unnecessary ones:

```
function formatNumber(n) {
    var parts = n
        .toExponential(3)
        .split(/[.e]/);

    var integral = parts[0];
    var fractional = '.' + parts[1];
    var exponent = 'e' + parts[2];

    fractional = fractional.replace(/\.?0+$/, '');
    exponent = exponent === 'e+0' ? '' : exponent;

    return integral + fractional + exponent;
}

nums.map(formatNumber)
// ["1", "5e-5", "2.547e-7"]
```

ES6:

```
const formatNumber = n => {
    const [, integral, fractional, exponent] =
        /(\d+)(\.\d+)(e.\d+)/.exec(n.toExponential(3));

    return integral +
        fractional.replace(/\.?0+$/, '') +
        (exponent === 'e+0' ? '' : exponent);
};
```